# UIActivityViewController Message Glitched Display

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've got an interesting issue. When attempting to share some text or a URL via a UIActivityViewController and then Messages, the message UI appears with what looks like invalid layouts (you can see below).

I've attempted eliminating as many variables as possible. My `AppDelegate.swift` is only composed of the following:

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

  let testVC = TestViewController()
  window?.rootViewController = testVC
  window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

  return true
}
```

And `TestViewController.swift` is simply

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let test = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(test, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

However once I press the message button, I'm shown the picture below with now way to exit. I've attempted creating a new project and added this same code and everything works fine, so I'm at a bit of a loss. Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to a library I was using that only appears in some cases. The library is FDFullscreenPopGesture for those curious.